# Trouble getting working directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is how I am trying to get the current working directory:

```
    char* ch;
    if( (ch = _getcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
    {
        cout << "Could not get working directory!" << endl;
    }
    // skonvertujme char* na string, s tym sa nizsie bude lahsie pracovat
    stringstream ss;
    string workingDirectory;
    ss << ch;
    ss >> workingDirectory;

    cout << workingDirectory << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
```

Which prints out:

```
C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Visual
```

Instead of the actual working directory:

```
C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Client\Debug
```

It seems like ti cuts everything after a space.

How can I get the working directory correctly even if there are spaces in the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>>` operator stops at the first space. Instead of the stringstream manipulation try

```
string workingDirectory(ch);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just replace this:

```
stringstream ss;
string workingDirectory;
ss << ch;
ss >> workingDirectory;
```

with this:

```
string workingDirectory(ch);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `getline(ss, workingDirectory)`

The reason that happens is that the `<<` operator in `stringstream` stops reading when it encounters whitespace.

Comment: Why use the string stream at all?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use your solution - which is overkill - use the [noskipws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/) io-manipulator like so:

```
ss >> noskipws >> workingDirectory;
```